# From the Torah itself how do we know that various names of God points to the same God?

Tags: names, tanach, theology

Jews believe that God, while having many names, is actually one.

So the idea is that El Elyon, Elohim, El Shadai, YHWH, Adonai, El, are just names mostly referring to the same being.

Is there any verses in the Torah that makes it clear, that all those are just names of the same God, instead of names of different gods?

Shema comes close to this, but one could argue that the Shema speaks of a new god. Then there are things like YHWH telling Moshe that he used to be known by a different name and now want to be known as YHWH.

These verses are intriguing but leave me with questions. I'm looking for a verse (or several verses) that gives a really strong proof.

Comment: Jim Thio, but Shema uses Elo/him (in a possesive form) to describe the oneness of Y/H/V/H!

Comment: Jim, consider [my comment on HodofHod's answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16694/from-the-torah-itself-how-do-we-know-that-various-names-of-god-points-to-the-sam#comment36297_16700) below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's a problem. Not to be presumptuous, but I too am one and yet I have many names. My mother called me Myron, my Gramma called me Myronu, my best friend called me Myr, my sergeant called me Private, my clients call me Mr. "Green", friends call me Meir or Pal, my nephew calls me Uncle Meir, strangers call my Buddy, and my boss calls me "Hey, you".

Comment: You raise an interesting point, but you haven't really covered the "*I'm looking for a verse (or several verses) that gives a really strong proof*" part of the question.

Comment: Who calls you Rick?

Comment: Alas, no one calls me Rick.  It's a nom de net.  I was surprised to see it show up after I posted my comment, so I edited the comment to make the last name match, but I couldn't change my first name, because I wouldn't know what my gramma or best friend would have called me..

Answer (score 18):

You mentioned this verse in passing, but as far as I can tell, it provides complete and convincing proof that G-d is known by multiple names.

Exodus 6:2-3, from [Mechon Mamre](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0206.htm):

> וַיְדַבֵּר אֱלֹהִים, אֶל-מֹשֶׁה; וַיֹּאמֶר אֵלָיו, אֲנִי יְהוָה.
>
> וָאֵרָא, אֶל-אַבְרָהָם אֶל-יִצְחָק וְאֶל-יַעֲקֹב--בְּאֵל שַׁדָּי; וּשְׁמִי יְהוָה, לֹא נוֹדַעְתִּי לָהֶם

Translation from [Chabad.org](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9867):

> **2**. God (Elo-him) spoke to Moses, and He said to him, "I am the Lord (YHVH)
> **3**. and I appeared to Abraham, to Isaac, and to Jacob with [the name] Almighty God (E-l Sha-dai), but [with] My name YHWH, I did not become known to them."

This is a verse that effectively synonymizes three names: Elo-him, YHVH, and (E-l) Sha-dai.

Comment: Yes, if this doesn't do it for you, what more do you want?

Comment: Okay cool. That sort that out.  Thanks. It's just 3 out of many names but it's a start.

Comment: @JimThio, Actually it covers all the ones you mentioned, since "*adonai*" is not technically a name of God, and neither is "*El Elyon*" ("*elyon*" is just an adjective that modifies "*El*").

Comment: Oh ya, the Lord means "El". Almighty God is El Shaddai right? And then YHWH is what again? My hebrew is close to 0 here. So that handles 3. A good start. Adonai means political lord. Here God doesn't say that he's the one and only almighty super God. He only says that he's the same god that Abraham used to worship though.

Comment: @JimThio - This can be un-translated as "Elo-him spoke to Moses ... I am YKVK and I appeared ... with [the name] El Shaddai ..."  Adonai is just a word we use to mean YKVK because we don't know how that sounds. "El" is not in there, but that just means "god" - lowercase g. But no, nowhere in Tanakh (AFAIK) does it say directly that G-d is the only god out there. Just the only god for the Jews.

Comment: @Charleskoppelman [Devarim 4:39](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0504.htm) - "Know this day, and set it unto your heart, that YKVK - He is the G-d - in the heavens above and on the earth below; there is no other."

Comment: @SethJ yup. good one.

Comment: @SethJ .... or if I wanted to be davka, it could be saying that there's nothing aside from the heavens and the earth.  But that doesn't really make sense given context.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman I think it is more than a stretch to say that. Just because the heavens and the earth are in the Pasuk immediately before the phrase "there is none other", does not mean that the latter is modifying the former. Punctuation is also key. I'm pretty sure (though not 100% positive) I punctuated it appropriately to convey the meaning of the Pasuk.

Comment: Hmm... That Deuteronomy  4:39 pretty much nail it.

Comment: I see. It DIDN'T nail it before to me because the bible translation do not translate it that way. The translation says God says I am the Lord. I think a more literal translation should be elohim (God) says I am YHWH. That'll be more clear. Why bible translation is so confusing?

Comment: And then we have scholars arguing that Deuteronomy 4:39 is written latter

Comment: @JimThio Based on precisely no historical evidence, written or otherwise. For some reason, these imagined editors decided to add one verse explaining why there's multiple names instead of just changing all the names to be the same, or adding those names to earlier verses.

There are reasons Jews and many scholars don't accept the Documentary Hypothesis, and that's because it makes no sense logically, and has no historical evidence.

Answer (score 3):

The Ten Commandments 1 and 2 are saying there is only one. Also once one says the Torah is from Hashem then and it says Hashem Echad (Shema) then anytime Hashem is written it has to be one. A contradiction can't be made when it is written by God.

Comment: But the question is not from the perspective of a believer.

Comment: Those commandments do not claim that there is only one God. It just says "Thou shalt have no other gods before Me", which one could argue actually implies that there **are** more than one.

Comment: If one doesnt believe then whats the question you could say any explanation and it cant be disputed. However,my reasoning is based on pure logic when an author writes they have to.be consistent esp when one writes an explicit idea.

Comment: This one is good enough actually. The question is not about whether God is one or not. The question is about whether from Torah alone one can reasonably conclude that the jews believe they have one God. Some, may still, however, argue that the God that speaks Ten commandments is not El Elyon (God most High) but one of his children that happen to baby sit Israel. http://www.thedivinecouncil.com/DT32BibSac.pdf

Comment: +1 anyway because it's a good point and because I always give +1 to all answers unless it really  messes up.

Comment: @jake Anochi Hashem... Anochi is one and once it starts with one the rest  has to be the same.This is the simplest reading give it to a 5 year old  and they will read it as such.

Comment: @sam. Hang on. What's Anochi again? Shema Yizrael. YHWH eloheinue, YHWH echad. I got that one right right? Oh that's not first commandment. That's another thing.

Comment: @sam, For the sake of argument, perhaps the *dibros* are YHWH talking and saying "I am YHWH your God... You shall have no other gods (i.e. Shaddai, El Elyon, Elohim etc.) before me..." All I'm saying is there is no proof from the *aseres hadibros* to what your saying. [And "anochi" just means "I" or "I am"; not necessarily uniquely. (Not everyone has to agree with Malbim.)]

Comment: @Jim Thio from the word Bereishis(first word of bible) till Yisroel(last word) it is the same author, and the same God who created the world was the same God who spoke the Ten Commandments.Once one is more fluent in the bible then one can see the many links.

Comment: @Jake the gods which are forbbiden is molten images which is avodah zarah and there are numorus examples of destroying other so called gods.

Comment: @sam, I agree with you; I'm playing devil's advocate here. The prohibition of idols and molten images is "לֹא-תַעֲשֶׂה לְךָ פֶסֶל, וְכָל-תְּמוּנָה". But before that already it says "לֹא-יִהְיֶה לְךָ אֱלֹהִים אֲחֵרִים, עַל-פָּנָי", which one could say means not to prohibit other (nonexistent) gods like the subsequent statement, but rather that of all the legitimate gods (Shaddai, El, etc.), I (YHWH) shall come first in the hierarchy; none should come "**before me**".

Comment: That would be another interpretation. Not only that there is no other God, but it's okay to worship other gods as long as YHWH is "first".

Comment: Christians also believe that the whole bible (they got thicker bible) is God's words. Who knows. I am sure you think Paul must have made up most new testaments. I bet the Samaritan also think that the jews must have made up all the books after the Torah. Atheists would believe that all books including Torah are made up by jews. And those authors don't even agree with one another. Who am I to know who's wrong?