# Elohim distinct from YHWH Elohim

Tags: theology

In Genesis 1 it is Elohim who created. In Genesis 2 from verse 4 we see that YHWH Elohim created Adam and the animals etc. From here onwards God is referred to as YHWH Elohim. Then we read of the heavenly council as sons of Elohim. Is there a difference between who Elohim is and who YHWH Elohim is?

Comment: Difference between "who" is incorrect. There is only one Hashem. These are just different names for different roles

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16694/from-the-torah-itself-how-do-we-know-that-various-names-of-god-points-to-the-sam

Comment: Thank you. How does one then interpret Psalm 82:1 Elohim stands in the congregation of el, among elohim He judges. Who then are the elohim and the congregation of the el?

Comment: The second Elohim means judges/ministers as in Exodus 22:27